# Dotnet commands not working even after installing .NET core SDK

Tags: c#, linux, command-line

I am trying to setup visual studio code for c# on Manjaro Linux

- I have installed VSC and .NET core 5.0 SDK through the package manager.
- The c# add-on is installed in VSC

With all of these installed correctly, why can't I use the dotnet command in the terminal?

Every time I try I get this error; `sh: dotnet: command not found`

Comment: Where did your package manager install the binaries to? Is that folder added to PATH?

Answer (score 1):

By default, `dotnet` is installed to `usr/share/dotnet`. Check if this path is added to the env var `$PATH`.

If you can't find it there, you could run on a terminal:

```sh
whereis dotnet
```

If no dotnet is found, the tool wasn't properly installed.

Also, did you close and reopen the terminal window after installing the SDK, as the [instructions stated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu)?